# Android: Expo Notification not showing on lock screen after inactivity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

On Android my expo app **does not show** notification (or they are receiving very late) after a certain **amount of time (like 3-5) being inactive and the phone being locked.**

**As soon as I unlock the phone I receive the pending notifications right away!**

When the phone is unlocked all notification receive properly and when I freshly lock the phone within the first 3 min (or so) the notification receive too. Just after being inactive, they won't show up.

I am not sure if this is some Android setting (this happens on Samsung A9 and Xiaomi Pocophone P1) or something I can set up in my app... On **iOS it all works fine**.

Do you have an idea what the problem could be? Other apps like Facebook, Instagram etc. work fine.

Comment: I think this is not an issue with the expo. This is an issue with the phone operating system or with the notifications permissions. Could you please check the same with other devices may be?

Comment: @mainak Unfortunately currently, I don't have another phone. But I also assume that it has something to do with the operation system. I am using WiFI only (no sim card). So I assume something gets to sleep (like my Wifi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. While sending the notification I had to set `priority` to `high`. [see expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/). Too bad nobody could help me with it. But I hope this answers the question for other people, if they face the same problem.

Comment: I did this still didn't work out for me. Please is there another way I get past doze mode?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, In some devices, the "lock screen notifications" option is turned off.so i had to set lockscreenVisibility value to public
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notificationchannelinput

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('messages', {
      name: 'messages',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
      sound: 'ring.wav',
      lockscreenVisibility:Notifications.AndroidNotificationVisibility.PUBLIC
    });
```